# How can I create a role with specified name in AWS CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-iam

I want to create a role with specified name in CloudFormation in AWS, but I don't know how to do it.

Generally, the resources are created in CloudFormation with a name which has added a hash code at the end.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to nominate a specific name for resources created in CloudFormation.

Names include the 'hash code' to guarantee uniqueness in case a resource already exists or the CloudFormation template is deployed multiple times.

It is possible to specify Tags, which can populate fields like `Name`, that is not the case for a Role.